# Python - Calculating Coordinates For KML

Tags: python, coordinates, kml

I have a script that rips coordinates from photographs. When run against one of my photographs, the coordinates are:

```
15 39.49,-88 59.53
```

When you look at that on Google Maps: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=15+39.49,-88+59.53

You see that clicking on the green pointer gives the following: `15.658167, -88.992167`

How is Google calculating the coordinates 15.658167, -88.992167 ?

Once I know the calculation I should be able to implement it into my script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the coordinates in degrees plus fractional minutes.

15 degrees and 39.49 minutes is being converted to decimal degrees by Google Maps.  So

15 + 39.49/60. = 15.6581666666666667

and

-88-59.53/60 = -88.99216666666666

Notice the second minus sign in the second equation since Google is assuming that it's 59.53 minutes more negative than -88 degrees.

Comment: Is not it minutes? "degrees plus fractional minutes"